# Does "readonly" provide something that "{get;}" doesnt when declaring a readonly property?

Tags: c#, readonly

This question might have been asked in a different way that I couldn't find anywhere, or it might be a misunderstanding by me that I'd really appreciate if someone clarifies it. what is the difference between

```
public readonly string something;
```

and

```
public string something {get;}
```

Comment: The first is a read-only field, the second a read-only property.

Comment: The distinction is important for things like WPF applications, since only properties can be data-bound.  Trying to data-bind a field will fail.